Can't resolve '@clerk/shared/router' in @clerk/elements
I am using Clerk Element on my sign-up flow for my React (typescript) webapp. Today my app stopped working with error:
./node_modules/@clerk/elements/dist/chunk-7WFXAEQQ.mjs:90:1
Module not found: Can't resolve '@clerk/shared/router'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@clerk/elements/dist/react/sign-up/index.mjs
./src/<my app code>
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@clerk/elements/dist/chunk-7WFXAEQQ.mjs:90:1
Module not found: Can't resolve '@clerk/shared/router'

My sign-up page has the following imports:
import * as Clerk from '@clerk/elements/common'
import * as SignUp from '@clerk/elements/sign-up'

Any ideas on how to debug further?

Resolved, for now. What worked for me was re-installing Clerk and then Clerk elements:
 npm install @clerk/nextjs
 npm install @clerk/elements

